# SQL select statement where one course more than other

Tags: sql

[image]

what I want is return Name A because A is the only one who scored English better than Geo.

The basic question is select all the student where english score > geo score

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select name
from t
where course in ('Eng', 'Geo')
group by name
having max(case when course = 'Eng' then score end) > max(case when course = 'Geo' then score end);
```

If you have only one score per name/course, you can also use `join`s such as:

```
select teng.name
from t teng join
     t tgeo
     on teng.name = tgeo.name and
        teng.course = 'Eng' and
        tgeo.course = 'Geo' and
        teng.score > tgeo.score;
```

Comment: Hi is case a function of sql?

Comment: @KEVINBOSS . . . `case` is a keyword in SQL for conditional expressions.